# Google chrome and safari browser data storage

Tags: google-chrome-extension, safari-extension

I want to know whether Google chrome and safari browsers currently support local data storage?

I need to store some data in browser level and need to query it. Is this browsers support local data storage?

Thank You,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they do, as part of their support for HTML 5, specifically HTML 5 Client-side Database Storage through an API.

You can see an example of it in action [here](http://webkit.org/demos/sticky-notes/). You can find a tutorial at [darkcrimson.com](http://blog.darkcrimson.com/2010/05/local-databases/). You can find the standard for it [at W3C](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/).